# Dynamic Service Strategies in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, strategy-pattern

How can I switch out a service on-the-fly and have all components (relying on the service) automatically be bound to the data on the new strategy?

I have a `Storage` service and two storage strategies, `StorageStrategyA` and `StorageStrategyB`. `Storage` provides the public interface to controllers and other components to interact with:

```
angular.module('app').factory('Storage', function ($injector) {
    var storage;
    var setStrategy = function (name) {
        storage = $injector.get(name);
    };

    setStrategy('StorageStrategyB');

    return {
        getItems: function () {
            return storage.getItems();    
        }
        // [...]
    };
});
```

But when the strategy is changed, the two-way binding breaks and the view doesn't update with items from `getItems()` from the new strategy.

I've created a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hUWMR3K460B5WB9CLUMy?p=preview) to illustrate the problem.

Is there a way to combine the strategy pattern with AngularJS and keep the two-way binding?

*Please note that in my actual app I cannot just call `Storage.getItems()` again after the strategy has been changed, because there are multiple components (views, controllers, scopes) relying on `Storage` and the service change happens automatically.*

**Edit:**
I have [**forked the Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nR1DqVaKoDqrFDndnfpu?p=preview) to highlight the problem. As you can see, the data in the upper part only updates because I manually call `Storage.getItems()` again after the strategy has been changed. But I cannot do that, because other component - for example `OtherController` - are also accessing data on `Storage` and also need to automatically get their data from the new strategy. Instead, they stay bound to the initial strategy.

Comment: Can you explain more on "because there are multiple components (views, controllers, scopes) relying on Storage and the service change happens automatically."

Comment: Of course: `Storage` is actually a specific service for handling projects. There is a view/controller to list projects, one to show some graphs and so forth. In addition, a `Client` service relies on the `Project` service. They are all on the same page and use the `Project`'s methods and data.

But they all don't care what strategy is used to persist the data. The strategy switches between *local* and *http*, whether there is an active connection or not.

When I call `getItems()` on strategy change, all the other parts would still work on the old strategy/data. At least that's what I assume.

Comment: I've updated my question with a new Plunker to better show the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript works on references. Your array items in app is same reference as items of strategyB items initially with the below statement and when you update the StrategyB items automatically **items** in your view gets updated(**since same reference**).

```
$scope.items = Storage.getItems();
```

So, when you switch strategy you are not changing the reference of **items**. It still points to StrategyB items reference.

You have to use the below mechanism to change the reference.

Then you can do something where you can [communicate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) between controllers to change the **items** reference.

Please find the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrVjlKG42jfsgTZRmaC7?p=preview) I have updated.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("updateStrategy");
```

And then update your item list and others.

```
$scope.$on("updateStrategy",function(){
  $scope.name = Storage.getName();
  $scope.items = Storage.getItems(); //Here changing the reference.
  //Anything else to update
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if somehow possible, I would like to keep my components relying on `Storage` clean of any workarounds. As far as they are concerned, the service just updated its data.

Comment: @bernhardw Updated my answer. Hope it makes it clear. Don't get confused between two way data binding and javascript references. They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

the two way binding is still ok, you have a reference issue.
when the AppController set up the $scope.items set to the StorageStrategyB items, then when you switch to StorageStrategyA, the AppController $scope.items is still set to StorageStrategyB items.

Comment: That's true, and that's my problem. I would like `items` to populate with data from the new strategy. `StorageStrategyA` in your example.

Comment: you can add a $scope.getItems to AppController that returns the Storage.getItems() and call that from the view: `ng-repeat="item in getItems()"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately multiple other components (even another service) rely on `Storage`, so while your suggestion works for that `ng-repeat`, it wouldn't everywhere else. Please see the edit of my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app').controller('AppController', function ($scope, Storage) {



    Storage.setStrategy('StorageStrategyB');

    $scope.current = Storage.getName();

    $scope.items = Storage.getItems();  

    $scope.setStrategy = function (name) {
        Storage.setStrategy(name);
        $scope.current = Storage.getName();
        $scope.items = Storage.getItems();  
        console.log( $scope.items);
        console.log($scope.current);
    };

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        Storage.addItem($scope.item);
        $scope.item = '';
    };

});
```

You forgot

```
 $scope.items = Storage.getItems();
```

nice question :)

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rKFaECL9KNd9q3zX5ovX?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but please see my note "Please note that [...]", the edit and the second Plunker :) The problem is that I have multiple other components also relying on `Storage`, and they don't update.